# Handling webServices call and cached data in Fragments

Tags: android

Good day, Sorry for the rather long post. this is more like a design decision than anything else. I have an activity which contains 4 fragments. Now i switch through the fragments through a slideMenu.
Each Fragment makes a call to a webservices and gets a JSONObject result vis an AsyncTask. I am looking for a structure where i would have to cache each JSONObject result
for each fragment . when the user switches between the fragments, it checks if a certain amount of time has expired and acts accordingly

-if cached time has expired, reload the network request again.
 -if not, use the cached JSONObject result and display to the user.

this means if i have an expiration time for like 6 hrs or rather the data from the backend updates every 6hrs,  I should only request from the webservice via the asynctask
once every 6 hours and other times just used the cached values instead.

My current implementation 
1. To have a set of global boolean variables via extending  the Application class to load for each fragments the first time.

```
public class MyApp  extends Application {

private boolean First_load_frag1 = true;
private boolean First_load_frag2= true;



    public void setLoadFrag1(boolean value){
        First_load_frag1 = value;
    }

    public boolean getLoadFrag1(){
        return First_load_frag1;
    }
}
```

1. in my fragments, i set them to true in onCreate(), use it to determine whether to request the first time and then set it to false so i don't have to anymore.
   then in my fragments OnResume() i check to see if the cached_time has expired or not. i do something like this

   @Override
       public void onResume(){
           super.onResume();
           public final static long MINUTE_MILLIS = 60000;

   ```
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 

     int mins = (int) ((cal.getTimeInMillis()/MINUTE_MILLIS) - (cached_timer/MINUTE_MILLIS);

     if(mins > 180){
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "on resume refresh data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           requestService();  //this sends a request to the webservice

     } else {


       cached_result = manager.getCachedJSONResult(CACHED_RESULT );


       if(cached_result != null){
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "on resume cached data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               loadCachedResult(cached_result);
       }

     }
   }
   ```

   This feels like a messy way of handling this situations to me. Taken into consideration application crashes and Activity lifecycles, is this a good solution of doing something like this oris there a more elegant way i can achieve this? Every input will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.first you need to create data structure for holding data for fragment

1. check in data structure that data is available for selected fragement and it is time for refresh data
   if yes then call load data(web service to load data) into fragment
   else
   load data from data structure and show in fragment.